# Json.net Source Error

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm using .net 4.0 with Visual Studio Express 2010 with the newest version of Json.net.
I've built a simple form application that should display parsed Json data from a website.
The data has been put into a string, but when I try to Deserialize into the class I have created, it asks me where the JsonConvert.cs file is and gives me this error :

> No Source Available
>
> Newtonsoft.Json.dll!Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(string value) Line 729
>
> Locating source for 'c:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\JsonConvert.cs'. Checksum: MD5 {30 55 70 37 e4 7c d7 ac df e0 5e 5f 25 5f 7a c6}
>   The file 'c:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\JsonConvert.cs' does not exist.
>   Looking in script documents for 'c:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\JsonConvert.cs'...
>   Looking in the projects for 'c:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\JsonConvert.cs'.
>   The file was not found in a project.

This is the Command that raises the error :

```
Account account = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Account>(json);
```

I Cant seem to find anybody else having this problem.  Anybody have any idea what is happening?

Comment: Have you added the Newtonsoft.Json.dll file as a reference to the project?

Comment: Yes its in the references.

Comment: Weird that your solution is looking for the class file when it shouldn't be seeing it at all when you've got a reference to the .dll. It's almost as if it's compiling Newtonsoft.Json when you build.

Comment: Yea that's kinda what i was thinking, but why would it do that?

Comment: I too am getting this error when attempting to call the JsonConvert.SerializeObject, did you ever find a solution to this issue?